# PrependTo, then remove itself on click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml

I have this piece of jQuery I created:

```
        $(function(){

            $("a img").click(function() {
               $("<div id=\"overlay\"></div>").hide().prependTo("body").fadeIn(100);

                $("body").css({
                    'overflow': 'hidden'
                }); 
            });

            $("#overlay").on("click", function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });

        })();
```

When I click an `img` inside an `anchor` tag, the overlay `div` appears. But now, after the overlay `div` has appeared I want to make it disappear (remove from the page) when I click on it.

I tried the above code, but it somehow doesn't work. Also the overlay `div` occupies  the entire viewport of the browser, if that is of any help.

Can somebody help me out on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delegate to an element that exists before the document ready event. Overlay does not.

```
jQuery('body').on('click','#overlay'.function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
```